# NSTextAlignment inverse of .Natural

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel

I understand that by using `NSTextAlignment.Natural` you allow a label draw it's content using the default righting direction for a given language, which helps heaps with localisation, allowing the label to draw it's text from left-to-right in languages like english/spanish/etc..., and from right-to-left in languages like arabic. Now my question is that I want to have a label draw in the opposite direction to .Natural, so in a left-to-right language the text should align to the right and in right-to-left languages it should align to the left.

I cannot find an NSTextAlignment enumeration option for this. so I was hoping somebody would give me some advice on how to accomplish this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that??

Comment: Say I have two labels side by side in a cell, one displaying the name of a product and the other it's price. It makes sense that it's alignments should be opposite.

Comment: So is this an objective-c question or a swift question?

Comment: Either or, the answer can be in both Obj-C or Swift.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Heaven knows why Apple don't offer a NSTextAlignmentNaturalInverse or equivalent.

Here is the code we use to achieve this in our producation app...

```
+ (BOOL)isLanguageLayoutDirectionRightToLeft
{
    return [UIApplication sharedApplication].userInterfaceLayoutDirection == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft;
}

someLabel.textAlignment = [UIApplication isLanguageLayoutDirectionRightToLeft] ? NSTextAlignmentLeft : NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: This approach can't be used in extension bundle likes today widget since there is no `UIApplication`.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks you @Oliver, here is what I ended up using in swift:

#### Extension

```swift
extension NSTextAlignment {
    static var invNatural: NSTextAlignment {
        return UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .left : .right
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```swift
myLabel.textAlignment = .invNatural
```

Comment: Very nice trick with `static var` to "extend" enum's cases. I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

I do no think that there is a text alignment "unnatural".

But you can retrieve the natural language direction from `NSLocale` with `+characterDirectionForLanguage:`. Having this, you can set set the alignment yourself.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
UInt dir = [NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:locale.localeIdentifier];
NSLog(@"%d", dir); // returns 1 for left-to-right on my computer (German, de_DE) Hey, that should be ksh_DE!
```

Comment: You shouldn't do something manually which is already done automatically. This can get very confusing with a bigger GUI.

Comment: 1. Please read the Q including the answer to *your* Q. 2. Please read the Q: "I want to have a label *draw* in the opposite". Draw, not layout text. 3. My answer uses a documented API.

Comment: You can't draw in a text view -.- Also my answer is officially documented as well

Comment: 1. Of course you can draw there. But this is pointless, because you can have a more complex layout depending on the writing direction. 2. *I* did not say, that your answer uses undocumented or "manual" features. I said that it is not an answer to his Q.

Answer (score 1):

In Apple's Internationalization and Localization Guide, under [Supporting Right-to-Left Languages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH17-SW2), they indicate that getting the layout direction should be done using `UIView`'s `semanticContentAttribute`. So you could implement something like the following:

```
extension UIView {
    var isRightToLeftLayout: Bool {
        return UIView.userInterfaceLayoutDirection(for: self.semanticContentAttribute) == .rightToLeft
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of not relying on things like `UIApplication`, which depending on whether you're working in an extension or not (eg the Today widget), you might not have access to.